# Issue in FsCalendar implementation iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, fscalendar

I am using FSCalendar in my application according to requirement I implemented everything but facing one problem. When I switch month using button then calendar scrolls to next or previous month but it showing 1 date as automatically selected which is not needed. First Image where I press on  [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0EIy.png).

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3s3s.png) its shows auto selected date.

```
 @IBAction func nextMonth(_ sender: UIButton){
    let t = calendar.currentPage.addingTimeInterval(24*60*60)
    let components = globalCurrentCalendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: t)
    yearParam =  String(components.year!)
    monthParam = String(components.month!)
    let mnth = components.month! + 1
    monthParam = String(mnth)
    let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .calendar, value: 1, to: t)
    monthScrollDate = date!
    self.calendar.select(self.formater.date(from:ConstantFile.dateToStringTemp(date: date!))!)
}
```

Comment: I think you do something by code. because in 1st image current date is fill with pink color and selected date is filled by border. In 2nd image 1 is filled by pink color. so double check you code.\

Comment: @Kuldeep yes I did with code and in first image today date is with pink and other date with border is actually not selected its just representation on an event on that day. If user selects any date it will also become pink color and then today date text colour will become pink......I have updated my code for IBAction of button.

Comment: you change calendar date by writing this line `self.calendar.select(self.formater.date(from:ConstantFile.dateToStringTemp(date: date!))!)`. You don't have to do anything on next previous button just need to change calendar currentPage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do below steps for next month.

1. Get `CalendarView` currentPage.
2. Create 1 Date with 1 Month addition in `CalendarView` currentPage.
3. set `CalendarView` currentPage by newly created date.

**For Next Month**

```
let currentMonth = self.calendarVW.currentPage
let nextMonth: Date? = gregorian.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: currentMonth, options: [])
self.calendarVW.setCurrentPage(nextMonth!, animated: true)
```

**For Previous Month**

```
let currentMonth = self.calendarVW.currentPage
let previousMonth: Date? = gregorian.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: currentMonth, options: [])
self.calendarVW.setCurrentPage(previousMonth!, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
        if monthPosition == .previous || monthPosition == .next {
        calendar.setCurrentPage(date, animated: true)
    }
}
```